# neo4j cypher: diamond shape relation

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph

[image]

I want to write a query that return the doc node where the `complex` node might have 2 or more `[COMPOSED_OF]` relation with nodes of type `keyword`

Comment: What cypher queries have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you start from category, can you try

```
START cat=<lookup category node>
MATCH (cat)-->()-[r:COMPOSED_OF]->()-[:FOUND_IN]->(doc)
with count(r) as composedCount, doc
WHERE composedCount>2
return doc
```

[Note that I have not really executed this]